# code generated UpperEmail property

Tags: c#, nhibernate

If I have in my domain entity `User` which have property

```
public virtual string UpperEMail { get; protected set; }
```

and it is mapped like this

```
Property(x => x.UpperEmail, m =>
{
    m.Length(150);
    m.NotNullable(true);
    m.UniqueKey("UniqueUpperEmail");
    m.Access(Accessor.Field);
});
```

How to generate this UpperEmail property with test data.

```
Account account = new Account()
{
   Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
   Email = "somemail@gmail.com",
   UpperEmail = "SOMEMAIL@GMAIL.COM"
};
```

Ofcourse I'm getting following error (I cannot set the value cause set accessor is inaccessible)

> not-null property references a null or transient value
>   Account.UpperEmail

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you consider that you need UpperEmail only as get accessor

```
public virtual string UpperEMail { get Email.ToUpper(); }
```